# What happens to all my assets outside US if I die?

Tags: united-states, inheritance, estate-planning, will

**The event:** I am Brazilian and a Green Card holder and I bought a house in Brazil.

**First question**: Do I need to register this house in my tax return here in US?

**Second question**: Suppose the scenario that I don't have a will and I die... what happens to my house in Brazil?

I am asking this because in my understanding, here in US, the estate (or IRS?) will have all my assets, bank accounts, etc, is this correct? In this case, this asset is outside the country... so, the same will happen? US will send some agent to take care of my assets in Brazil?

Comment: "The US" only cares about possible taxes due on your foreign assets.  More importantly, **state law**, not the Feds, handles probate.  Issues like this are why you **really** need a will, and an executor who can handle things not only here but in Brazil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First question: Do I need to register this house in my tax return here in US?

There is no "registration" of foreign property (whether real estate or stocks or anything else) on a US tax return, *but*, as a permanent immigrant, your world-wide income is subject to US tax, and so I hope that you have been declaring the *income* generated by these foreign properties (e.g. rental income, dividends, interest, etc) on your US tax returns all these years. If not, I recommend that you file amended returns.

> Second question: Suppose the scenario that I don't have a will and I die... what happens to my house in Brazil?

This is more of a legal question than a financial one, and is better asked over on Law.SE. *Someone* will need to settle your estate in the US, too , and you better be prepared to reveal whether you have any dependents in Brazil or in the US in order to get more useful answers.